# Postgres: Grouping data with overlapping group members

Tags: postgresql, group-by, grouping

I have a data_points table with millions of rows like so:

```
data_stream_id   time_slot              value
1                2019-01-01 00:00:00    100
2                2019-01-01 00:00:00    35
3                2019-01-01 00:00:00    80
1                2019-01-01 00:00:01    110
2                2019-01-01 00:00:01    30
3                2019-01-01 00:00:01    70
1                2019-01-01 00:00:02    120
2                2019-01-01 00:00:02    30
3                2019-01-01 00:00:02    50
```

I need to get time series data for groups of data_streams (where values are summed if multiple data_streams).

For example with groups:

```
group_id    data_streams
a           1, 3
b           3
```

I would want results:

```
group_id         time_slot              value
a                2019-01-01 00:00:00    180
a                2019-01-01 00:00:01    180
a                2019-01-01 00:00:02    170
b                2019-01-01 00:00:00    80
b                2019-01-01 00:00:01    70
b                2019-01-01 00:00:02    50
```

The tricky part is a data_stream can be included in multiple groups. So I can't just do a simple `SELECT` from the data_points table (since that would only allow each data_point to be counted once). I tried doing a `LEFT JOIN` to a `values` mapping like so:

```
SELECT    v.group_id, dp.time_slot, sum(dp.value)
FROM      data_points dp
LEFT JOIN (values (1,'a'),(3,'a'),(3,'b')) as v(data_stream_id, group_id)
ON        dp.data_stream_id = v.data_stream_id
GROUP BY  v.group_id, dp.time_slot
ORDER BY  v.group_id, dp_time_slot
```

But is that going to scale poorly with large groups? It basically duplicates the rows for a data_stream if it is in multiple groups.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=73c668c4b6befc051ba2b900e20c2930)

I am not quite sure why you are using a `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN` instead of an `(INNER) JOIN`. The `LEFT JOIN` only makes sense if there would be a time slot which is not contained by any group (in your case `data_stream_id = 2`; see fiddle). But you are only interested in those data sets which have correlated groups. So, you should use a simple `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    g.group_id,
    dp.time_slot,
    SUM(value) AS value
FROM data_points dp 
JOIN groups g
ON dp.data_stream_id = g.data_stream
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Assuming that the groups aren't in their own table (the groups are generated at run time dynamically), is doing what I did with `(values (1,'a'),(3,'a'),(3,'b')) as v(data_stream_id, group_id)` essentially the same thing?

Comment: Yes, this would be the same in that case. One difference regarding performance is that thr table could have some indexes which could be used.Your dynamically generated value cannot.